# Who are the named prisoners in "Conviction"?

Tags: starcraft-2

As I was fighting my way through a Dominion Prison Ship, I found a single, named prisoner.

[image: Gerdes, I]

Mr. Gerdes wasn't the only one I found, but I didn't recognize any of the prisoner's names. Are they referencing something in-universe? Cameos or easter egg references?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*In order of appearance:*

[image: before the option to build virophages]

**Gerdes, I:** [Ian Gerdes](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/Ian/Gerdes) has been a level designer for Blizzard since 2011. He also has an [NPC named after him](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=64116/ian-gerdes) in Mists of Pandaria.

[image: at virophage option]

**Sones, J:** [Jake Sones](http://www.linkedin.com/in/jakesones) was a level designer for Blizzard from 2009-2012. He has also has an [NPC named after him](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=52015/captain-jake-sones) in Cataclysm.

[image: in the timed portion]

**Adams, D:** [David Adams](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/david-m-adams/4/151/4a9) has been a level designer for Blizzard since 2004. He also has an [NPC named after him](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=27760/grizzly-d-adams) in Wrath of the Lich King.

I don't know what the phrases are about; probably in-jokes at Blizzard, if anything.

*(special thanks to Qyratar for spotting Sones, J)*

Comment: Got any more info on the other prisoners?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Haven't gotten to that mission myself, but if you can post some names I can try out my Google-fu again.

Comment: Aight, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Just did this one. Adams, D was the only additional one I found, let me know if you spot any more.

Comment: Hmm I always thought there was more.

Comment: @Resorath: If you can find 'em I'll add 'em, but I've been through twice now specifically looking for more and didn't find any.

Comment: I found Sones, J in the room where you can spawn 4 Virophages, Gotta find 'em all! ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zyI8o.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

**Gerdes, I** is a reference to [Ian Gerdes](http://iangerdes.com/) who is a Level Designer at Blizzard.

He also [appears in World of Warcraft](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=64116/ian-gerdes) and is in the credits for Mist of Pandaria.

He is [rumored](http://www.titanpedia.info/view/Ian_Gerdes) to be working on there next Blizzard project code name Titan.

I have tried finding some information on the quote, but so fare [no luck](http://twitter.com/blemx/status/312692466522415106) more than [one place](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/6891641646).

**Adams, D** is a reference to [David (Dave) Adams](http://www.diablowiki.net/Dave_Adams) Lead Level Designer on Diablo 3.

He also worked on StarCraft: Ghost, World of Warcraft The Burning Crusade and Wrath of the Lich King and there is a [character](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=27760/grizzly-d-adams) named after him(some think it is a reference to Grizzly Adams, but he looks more like David Adams).

I could not find any [information](http://twitter.com/blemx/status/313759137454505985) on his quote either.

Answer (score 0):

As the lines are from Blizzard staff, there's no way (short of getting them to admit it) to know for certain, but the line 'death sentence on twelve systems' is almost exactly a quote from Star Wars 'A New Hope', when Luke is accosted in the cantina in Mos Isley, the Walrusman's partner Cornelius Evazan uses the line to intimidate Luke "You'd better watch yourself, we're wanted men! I've got the death sentence on twelve systems!"

The other two quotes are just too vague without some sort of context...